# How to request files for download aync in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `angularjs` and would like to provide a download button.

Problem: the button triggers a long running (15sec) process in the backend before the file is returned from the backend. The user should not be blocked meanwhile.

So I thought I could fetch the file in the background with angularjs on click, and offer it for download when it is received async.

```
<a ng-href="{{service.pdf()}}" target="_blank">download</a>

function pdf() {
    return "http://path.to.the.service/filename.pdf";   
}
```

This way I'd directly open another page. Which works, but I'd like to fetch it in the background, not opening a new window.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best solution is use this html code for you button? Let's try this:

```
<a ng-href="{{service.pdf()}}" target="_self">download</a>
```

But also you can do this with AngularJS. For example you have code like below:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="downloadFile()" name="button">Download file</button>
```

ng-click call you downloadFile() function. You can perform your download action in this function:

```
$http.get('/path/to/your/file', { responseType: 'blob' })
.then((response) => {
    var windowUrl = $window.URL || $window.webkitURL;

    var anchor = angular.element('<a></a>');
    anchor
    .attr({
      href: windowUrl.createObjectURL(response.data),
      download: 'file.txt',
    });
    anchor[0].click();
  }
});
```

This solution also works fine for APIs with token-based authorization (with interceptors). But if you want to save blob files in IE and Mozilla, you should add some more code.

Comment: This will not work for FF or IE. You will be able to download 1 file but not multiple files.

Comment: Yes, you right. If you want to download file on IE, you can you use msSaveOrOpenBlob: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772332(v=vs.85).aspx. For FF you must add anchor into your DOM with 'display: none' CSS rule, invoke click action and remove after. It works also for multiple files, if you call this function two or more times.

Comment: `_self` works great BUT I'd like to offer it as a download. For now the file is opened inline in the browser.

Comment: Plus I have to support any browser type.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a hidden iframe to download the file. This can be used in a scenario to download multiple files in one page - where the `<a>` method will not work on FF.

```
  $scope.downloadUrl = function (url) {
        var oIframe = window.document.createElement('iframe');
        var $body = $(document.body);
        var $oIframe = $(oIframe).attr({
            src: url,
            style: 'display:none;'
        });
        $body.append($oIframe);
   }
```

You can download multiple files in Chrome & FF, however IE you are out of luck.

Comment: I have to use a method that supports any browser, but thanks anyways.